# How to make a larger menu font in a Windows application?

Tags: c++, fonts, menu, mfc

I have a Windows app written in C++ (using MFC) - Visual Studio 6.0.

A user wants all the menu items (ie. from the main application menu) to be larger because he has a big monitor. The app allows the (client) text inside the window to be drawn larger so that isn't a problem. It's just the menus.

I can get the menu as a CMenu object and from that derive the HMENU handle. I don't particularly want to have to change to owner-draw just to make a simple change like that.

**Is there a way of telling Windows to use a larger version of the system font, just for menus,** and just for the current app? The user doesn't want to make fonts larger for all apps (via the Control Panel) because that breaks other things.

A solution should be compatible with Windows XP onwards - not everyone is running the latest versions of Windows. It also should *not* affect the font used in dialog boxes as they are laid out in such a way that a larger font is likely to make part of the text disappear.

Comment: Are you sure you want "just for the menus"? That's a lot more work than to replace the system font (which you should do anyway).

Comment: Will that affect dialog box contents? Making fonts larger with the control panel affected tree-views but not dialog box contents, which is almost OK. The suggestion of SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS made only the menus larger. Why should I replace the system font? Or do you mean, replace the system font to achieve what I want here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some tools like the BCG Library or others like Codejock, Prof-UIS.

All this libraries use custom draw for the menus. So there it is possible to enlarge the fonts for the menu just for this program.

Another simple way would be: Just update to a newer VS-Version and you get the new menus incl. the possible flexibility of owner draw menus for free...

BTW: The user has the same problem, with other programs, he should find a better solution like scaling the size of the display font... and yes this is for all applications

Answer (score -1):

You can try SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS and SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS and modifying lfMenuFont of NONCLIENTMETRICS.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: *"just for the current app"*

Comment: This suggestion certainly works in that I could make the menus satisfyingly large. However it did affect all apps.